# Retrieving data from MySQL DB and navigating in the Form by button click in Java

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I coded a button/listener for navigating previous.

Previous button action performed code is below;

```
private void PreviousBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    try{
       String sql = "select ItemID,ItemName from druginfo";
       pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
       rs=pst.executeQuery();
       while(rs.next()){ 
       String id = rs.getString("ItemID");
       String name = rs.getString("ItemName");

       if(evt.getSource()==PreviousBtn){
           if(rs.previous()){
               if(rs.isFirst()){
                   PreviousBtn.setEnabled(false);
                   NextBtn.setEnabled(true);
               }
               IDcombo.addItem(id);
               Namecombo.addItem(name);
           }
       }
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Problem is, **my window stuck when I press Previous button** (so not working the code). Have I made any mistake here?

Comment: any exceptions are you getting on console?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: In fact, I'd argue that if that (uncompilable) code (snippet) above were indented more logically, it would make it clear that the loop and if test are 'fighting each other'!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you are not able to use `rs.previous()` method which is causing the issue.

Try to create statement with below lines,

```
pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql,
        ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
        ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: The Java docs (which you should consult before making an answer) for [`ResultSet.previous()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#previous--) suggest that it throws a number of helpful (or at least informative) exceptions that would dump a stack trace (given the above code) on failure.

Comment: @Vishal Zanzrukia result is same..Just stuck the window.. There no any exceptions showing either :(

Comment: what do you mean by stuck the window ?

Comment: @Vishal Zanzrukia nothing happens in the window..also I can't close it:(